# How could I make a partition of my ssd boot to linux without harming the rest of the data?

Tags: partition, opensuse, bootable

I recently installed openSUSE on my laptop. The installation appears to work fine, until you turn it off, and find that the laptop doesn't recognize that the OS is bootable. However, if I plug in the USB installation drive again, it does recognize the OS, and I can boot to it just fine. I have seen several users have the same problem, and as far as I can tell, none of them solved it. My best solution I have come up with involves putting the ISO on a partition of the ssd, and just booting from that every time. The main problem, though, is that I don't even know if that's possible without wiping the rest of the drive.

tl;dr (if you do that here), I need to make a partition of my drive bootable without wiping the whole thing.

Comment: Read `man grub-install`. Also, boot from a LiveCD/USB and ensure the "Boot" flag is set on the correct partition.

Comment: Most tools that create installer from ISO, erase entire drive as they write the ISO in a hybrid DVD/flash drive configuration. So do not use any tool that uses dd or dd under the hood. Not sure if this works with openSUSE or not: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I figured it out! for some reason, the bootloader that is installed with xfce is broken, so I just installed gnome as my desktop, since I was planning to use it sometimes anyway, and then just installed xfce later.